Visual code terminal is not working what should I do
I am learning Java and my code shows no problem but my terminal is not working. What should I do? It shows your classpath is not there.
I have tried watching some videos but it doesn't work at all. It shows java basic.java is not on the class path. Only syntax errors are reported.
My code is:
import java.util.*;

public class javaBasics {

    public static void main(String args[] ) {
         int age = 22;
         if (age >= 18) {
             System.out.println("adult : drive, vote");
         } else {
            System.out.println("not adult");
         }
    }

My terminal is showing:
PS C:\Users\achah\OneDrive\Desktop\java learning\app.java> javaBasics.java
javaBasics.java : The term 'javaBasics.java' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ javaBasics.java
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (javaBasics.java:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException 


"Post your code" has a somewhat specific meaning on Stack Overflow, by the way - [mre] provides some good guidelines.

seems like VS is not recognizing your code as a Java program or is not set up to execute Java programs (I do not use VS, sorry)

Did you install this? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack

Java in Visual Studio Code

yes i have installed that extension

Hello Chahat, If I am not mistaken, the name of the file containing the code you show is: app.java, for a Java application to work, the name of the file, must be the same as the main class, that is, change the name of the file to:  javaBasics.java and try to run it.

Hello, you may need to check your file name to make sure it's the same as the class name. Then, depending on the answer, switch to the directory where the Java file is located and compile the code using the JAVAC javaBasics.java command. Run the file in a directory using the java javaBasics.java or use the run button to run the file.

Follow the steps to resolve the issue:
1. Compile the Java code:
Before running, the javaBasics.java file should compiled first. In your terminal, navigate to the directory where your Java file is located and then use this command:

javac javaBasics.java

This will create a javaBasics.class file in your directory.
2. Run the compiled class:
Run the compiled Java program with the following command:

java javaBasics

Note:

Don't include the .java extension when running the class. You only use the .java extension when compiling.
Ensure that your file name javaBasics.java exactly matches your class name javaBasics.

If you still encounter issues, please share the error message, and I'll help further!

I am facing same issue same error

Hello, if you try to switch to the directory where the javaBasics.java file is located, and then use the JAVAC javaBasics.java command to compile the code, can it run? Or use the run button to run the file.

I hope your Java file name and class name are both the same.
for eg. if the file name is basic.java then the class name is also the same - public class basic {...}
You can run the code in two ways.

Without compile
java javaBasics.java

With compile
javac javaBasics.java
java javaBasics


